# What is the Time Complexity of if(false) and while(true&& false ) ?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, time-complexity

Time Complexity of

if ( true ) ?

while ( true && false ) ?

Comment: Some nanoseconds, doubt that you will ever need it.. where is this question coming from?

Comment: Surely an optimizing compiler would recognize that those comparisons are pointless and not omit any code for them?

Answer (score 2):

Time Complexity for simple Multiplication, Addition or Boolean, etc is `O(1)`. which is very low and is considered constant-time operations.

Answer (score 1):

**if-else statement are constantly O(1)**

*true && false* give us **false** result for while loop, so it's never been executed for this situation, complexity also will be **O(1)**